# Data from Last and Current year

Tags: date, apache-superset

I want to create a Chart that compares the revenue of the current year with the previous year. I didn't find any documentation (yet) on how to code the date for current and last Calendar year.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It’s now October and I want to compare the revenue from last Calendar year (Jan-Dec) to this year (Jan-Oct).
At this moment I can select last year, which goes back to October last year and not January last year.